# Inserting data from a html form into MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql

I want a student to be able to calculate some equation and then send it to his cell in the `members` database.

Here is what I have tried:

```
<?php
//connect
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
mysql_select_db("members");
//insert
$val3 = $_POST["result"];
$insert_query = "INSERT INTO users (results) VALUES ('$val3')";
$insertion_result = mysql_query($insert_query);
$query = mysql_query($insert_query) or die(mysql_error());
//check whether the data insertion was successful
if(!$insertion_result)
echo "<p>Sorry! Something went wrong.</p>";
else
echo "<p>Thanks! Your form has been processed.</p>";
?>
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ). Your code has a serious SQL injection vulnerability!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without an explanation, the exact problem you're having is unclear. It appears you are accidently inserting the row twice.

```
$insertion_result = mysql_query($insert_query);
$query = mysql_query($insert_query) or die(mysql_error());
```

Each of these submits the query, resulting in the row being inserted multiple times. All you need to do is remove the `$insertion_result` line.

In addition, as Benjamin stated in a comment, mysql_* functions are deprecated. Most likely mysqli is what you want.

```
$query = mysqli_query($insert_query) or die(mysqli_error());
```

The functions are nearly identical, just add an `i` on the end.

Comment: thnx so much 4 reply .. i did what u said and its kinda work ,,, now i think my issue with the SESSION cuz when ever i try to update the student result cell its always update the first user that i login with ,, u know what i mean right ?

Comment: Do you have a page where you logout before logging in as the next student? That page should have session_destroy(); somewhere in it, which should wipe all the session vars.

Comment: i create logout page ,, but still the same ,,, all result go to the same cell

Comment: I'd recommend creating a new question. Include the code with the $_SESSION variables in it and clearly state what your problem is. That way everyone can get a chance to help you.

Comment: ok i will now ,,, thanx 4 helping